# $\lim_{x \to 2}{\frac{x^3+3x^2-12x+4}{x^3-4x}}$

Tags: limits

Find $$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^3+3x^2-12x+4}{x^3-4x}$$ How do you get to your solution? Thanks in advance. I have tried factoring out $x^3$ to no avail.

Is there an algebraic solution? I don't know L'H rule.

Comment: L'H rule is applicable.

Comment: @Artes I'm not sure what you're referring to. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^3+3x^2-12x+4}{x^3-4x}=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{(x-2)(x^2+5x-2)}{x(x+2)(x-2)}=3/2$$

Answer (score 2):

Divide top and bottom by $x-2$, and then substitute in $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{x^3+3x^2-12x+4}{x^3-4x}=\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{3x^2+6x-12}{3x^2-4}=\dfrac{3}{2}$$
In the second step, I used L'Hopital's rule.